# Trying to use the Infinite Scroll Plugin on my xamarin android (Mvvmcross)

Tags: android, xamarin, mvvmcross

The problem is that it throws the exception

> "Failed to Construct and initialize the ViewModel"

but if I download the example from GitHub https://github.com/HBSequence/Sequence.Plugins works. (30/09/2021 - corrected hyperlink)

my **MainViewModel**

```
 private readonly IIncrementalCollectionFactory  _incrementalCollectionFactory;
   
    private readonly int _numberListPageSize = 30;
    private ObservableCollection<NumberViewModel> _numbers;

    public MainViewModel(IIncrementalCollectionFactory incrementalCollectionFactory)
    {
        _incrementalCollectionFactory = incrementalCollectionFactory;
    }

    public ObservableCollection<NumberViewModel> Numbers
    {
        get
        {
            if (_numbers == null)
            {
                //async (count, pageSize) 
                // The IncrementalCollectionFactory returns a generic ObservableCollection. In this example, 
                // it returns ObservableCollection<NumberViewModel>. Replace this with your own ViewModel.

                _numbers = _incrementalCollectionFactory.GetCollection(async (count,pageSize)=>
                {
                    ObservableCollection<NumberViewModel> newNumbers = new ObservableCollection<NumberViewModel>();

                    // Call an async method here to load the data from a data source that supports paging.
                    // This is a dummy implementaion.

                    await Task.Run(() =>
                   {
                        for (int n = count; n < (count + pageSize); n++)
                        {
                            NumberViewModel numberViewModel = new NumberViewModel();
                            numberViewModel.Value = n;
                            newNumbers.Add(numberViewModel);
                        }
                    });

                    //var pagedNewsEntities = await _newsInteractor.GetNewsAsync(pageSize);

                    return newNumbers;
                }, _numberListPageSize);
            }

            return _numbers;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does the inner exception tell you?

Comment: i solved it by adding the infiniteScrollPluginBootstrap class ,Thank you